# IOS FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink Still Beta?

Tags: ios, facebook, fbdialogs

So I'm trying to use the native share dialog, and no matter what I do, I'm still getting this prompt back that the feature is in beta, and not currently available. I know this was the case, however this was suppose to have been removed from beta. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/05/20/sharing-made-simple-for-ios-apps/

Anyone happen to know whats going on here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you upgraded your Facebook app to the latest version in the app store?

Comment: Oh wow, how bloody terrible. So yeah that was indeed the problem. Good call Ming. However, it was still switching to the FB app previously and trying to post. This seems like a potentially huge customer problem, as anyone that doesn't update their FB app is going to be sent there, and seemingly get the beta message feature unless something odd was going on. Unfortunately now I can't downgrade the FB app to test this further.

Comment: It will only switch over for the older versions if you've called [FBSettings enableBetaFeature:], otherwise it will not, it will just return a nil.